# Reference for the Gibbs variational principle/dual characterization of KL

Tags: probability, reference-request, math-history

Let $P,Q$ be two probability distributions. Then, one has the following dual characterization of their Kullback-Leibler divergence (relative entropy):

$$
D(P \,\|\,Q) = \sup_f ( \mathbb{E}_P[f(X)] - \log \mathbb{E}_Q[e^{f(X)}] ) \tag{1}
$$
This characterization is sometimes referred to as *Gibbs variational principle*, or *Donsker-Varadhan* formula; however, I couldn't track where it was first proven (there is often a reference to a paper of and Donsker Varadhan from 1983, but I couldn't find, in there, where (1) is actually established).

> Where was (1) established first, specifically? What to cite?

Comment: Note 4.1 of Ramon van Handel's lecture notes on High-Dimensional Probability claims (and to that end, cites) that it was first established in Theorem III on page 131 of "Elementary Principles in Statistical Mechanics" by Gibbs in 1902, but it's not clear to me that that formula is there either...

Comment: @J.G Yes, I have no idea how that Theorem III is even related to KL divergence... I take it as "Gibbs used an approach similar to the very general idea underlying this dual characterization", but even that seems tenuous.

Comment: So, it apparently is not proven in the Donsker—Varadhan paper from 1983, but instead in Lemma 2.1 from their 1975 paper (first in the series, not the fourth), and people citing the 1983 one just... couldn't tell the similar titles apart?
Remains to know if it the first time it was actually explicitly proven somewhere...

Comment: Still, glad you at least found a more accurate reference!

Comment: You can also look at Bob Gray's Elements of Information Theory.