# Interpretation of the variational representation of KL divergence.

Tags: probability, statistics

I saw the following result (from [Corollary 4.15](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.hse.ru/data/2016/11/24/1113029206/Concentration%2520inequalities.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjdlO-DlLLvAhVKeH0KHSllAVQQFjABegQIFBAC&usg=AOvVaw3YFkNs3OYkgEtNDCis_crS)) about the variational interpretation of the KL divergence being used in a paper:

Let $P$ and $Q$ be two probability distributions on the same space. Then
\begin{align}
D(Q\|P)=\sup_Z\Big(\mathbb{E}_Q[Z]-\log\mathbb{E}[e^Z]\Big),
\end{align}
where the supremum is taken over all random variables such that $\mathbb{E}[e^Z]<\infty$.

In another different paper I read, they substituted a function into $Z$, and some probability distributions into $P$ and $Q$ to get a lower bound on the KL divergence.

I noticed that the same function with different inputs can be substituted into the the $Z$ terms, i.e., a function with one set of inputs for the first $Z$ term and the same function with another set of inputs for the second $Z$ term. Why is this the case? I thought the substitution for $Z$ must be kept the same. Thanks.

Comment: This may help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3419509/reference-for-the-gibbs-variational-principle-dual-characterization-of-kl

Comment: Where do Boucheron-Lugosi-Massart use different functions ("$Z$") in the two terms? (also, your order of $P,Q$ is inverted, wrt to the result and the corollary from the book you cite.)

Comment: Yes, my bad. I'm saying it was used in another paper where two different functions were substituted into Z. The paper is https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.07809, proof of lemma 1 (in appendix).

Comment: Looking at that proof, it looks like they are using a specific function $\lambda f$, the same for both terms (first inequality after A.1, before A.2). No?

Comment: Yes, but doesn't inputting different things into the function f(.,.) make them different? Or does it not matter? I can't seem to convince myself that they are the same.

Comment: So, think of $Z=f(X,Y)$ as a function of $(X,Y)$; $P$ and $Q$ are two possible probability distributions for $(X,Y)$, and you get to choose $f$.

Comment: Ok, I get it. Thanks for taking the time out to help!

Comment: No worries at all. It's quite easy to get lost in the notation...